# What is the best way to access another CakePHP's Model in a Controller?

Tags: cakephp

Say I got two Controllers like this `Table1sController`, and `Table2sController`.
With corresponding models: `Table1sModel`, `Table2sModel`.

In the `Table1sController`, I got this:

```
$this->Table1sModel->action();
```

Say I want to access some data in `Table2sModel`.

How is it possible to do something like this in `Table1sController`?
I have tried this in Table1sController:

```
$this->Table2sModel->action();
```

But I received an error message like this:

> Undefined property: Table1sController::$Table2sModel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways to go here.

If your models have defined associations (hasMany, etc.), then you can access that model's methods (assuming you're in Model1Controller) with:

```
$this->Model1->Model2->method();
```

If there is no model association between the two models, but you want to be able to use the Model2's methods, you can add an entry in the $uses attribute of model1Controller.  See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#components-helpers-and-uses

Finally, if it's a transitory connection (you don't want the overhead of loading other models every time, because you're only rarely going to access model2), check out the manual's section on creating / destroying associations on the fly, at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Answer (score 2):

Something is inherently wrong with what you are doing.

In any controller, you can specify $uses = array('Table1sModel', 'Table2sModel', 'LolModel') and use each Model you need in your controller. You are not calling another controller to access a Model. Models are for data access, you access the needed ones directly from any controller.

I understand, that many MVC examples are almost always show you one page of one controller with one model which is horribly wrong as 99% of the cases you have one site from one controller using many different parts of different models.

(If you really need to call an action, use $this-requestAction())